# Need some help creating a quiz with radio buttons

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I don't know how to get it to say the answer was right or wrong.
So far I have this:

```
private bool CheckTheAnswer()
{
        if (radioButton2_CheckedChanged)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

But it isn't right. So I am confused on how to do it.

Comment: Confused on how to do what? Could you expand your explanation on what you want your quiz to do?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "RadioButton2" always holds the correct answer, you would just check the `Checked` property (`IsChecked` in WPF)

```
private bool CheckTheAnswer()
{
    return RadioButton2.Checked;
}
```